# how to detect if screen is locked if KeyGuard is not set - Android?

Tags: android, keyguard, screen-off

I want to know if screen is locked or not, when the `SCREEN_OFF` is broadcasted while user doesn't set `KeyGuard`?

Answer (score 0):

1.Take a look in the KeyguardManager documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html)

2.Try this code

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
           //screen is locked & check Keyguard is enabled or Not.
          KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);  

          Log.v(TAG,""+keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode());

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
           
 
        }
    }
 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you for help, but as I say in the question `KeyGuard` is not set ... so `inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()` return `false`

Comment: You didn't get it, what if the device isn't secured using `KeyGuard` , then using `KeyGuardManager` is absolutely useless.